# How to use to_param on only one method - or disable for other methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a `to_param` in my model so I can find orders by their tokens instead of user ID's in the URL. This is for guest users who are not signed in. I do this so other users won't be able to view other peoples orders or just anybody in general.

**I have this in my model:**

```
validates :order_token, presence: true
validates :order_token, uniqueness: true
before_validation :generate_token, on: :create

def generate_token
  begin
    self.order_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(28, false)
  end while self.class.find_by(order_token: order_token)
end

def to_param
  order_token
end
```

**In my controller I use it with this:**

```
def order_confirmation
  @order = Order.find_by(order_token: params[:order_token])
end
```

Though, I want this `find` or `find_by` to be limited to only the `order_confirmation` method

When users are signed in, I do want their actual order ID's in the URL (everything for signed in users is protected with cancancan gem). This way things are more convenient for them.

How can I limit the `to_param` override to only be available for one method only?

MY Routes:

```
resources :orders do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

Comment: With guest users, why not automatically assign them a session id? That way you are not reliant on what is contained in the params hash.

Comment: Can you correct grammar in your question "How can I limit the to_param override to only be available for one method only?"

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Thats probably a better idea than my current remedy but I am also new to coding and haven't done much manual session coding - as in creating a sessions controller, or similar.  But wouldn't a session be limited to when a user deletes cookies? I do want users to be able to reference the page in the future if they need be.

Comment: @uno yes if the user deletes their session cookies then they'll lose all their associated data. I don't recommend manually reimplementing logins by yourself - use an established and proven gem like `devise` - here is a read me on how to implement guest logins: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Comment: also be aware that there is a character limit in the amount of data you can place in the URL to extract data into the params hash.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually am using Devise already.  I like the system I have but what I'm looking to do is basically for aesthetics.  If a user is signed in an have access (using cancan), I think they should have the actual order :id in their URL - but if I don't find a way I'll just use a 28 digit token as the way to find the order.

Comment: You should note that replacing the ID with a token is really just security by obscurity and while it makes enumeration more difficult is not a replacement for properly authorizing resources.

Comment: Yes i know - but no information such as credit cards or addresses will ever be in the order confirmation and 2 i doubt anyone will go around trying to guess a 28 digit code to find other peoples orders just to see their name.  I may even create a second token for an order to have as order/:order_token/confirmation/:conf_token just to made things hard - and i believe shopify does that. or something very similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the to_param issue.  I just simply removed it and reorganized the routes for the specific member route.....

**When using:**

```
  resources :orders, param: :order_token do
      get 'order_confirmation', :on => :member
  end
```

In my routes, I am able to go to the URL i want. Although, after an order is created, it still directs me to a route using the :id.

**I then change my redirect to:**

```
redirect_to order_confirmation_order_path(@order.order_token)
```

**And it works.**

I also removed my `to_param` override.

Answer (score 0):

[Overriding Named Route Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

You can use the `param` option when defining resources to override the default resource identifier.  In order to have a different identifier depending on the route you can use the `only` and `except` options to specify which routes to include or exclude respectively.

You will need to create a `resources` block for each identifier.  You can then define which routes belong to which identifier.

In order to update the `to_param` method for URL generation you will need to be able to tell what action you are in, and therefore which identifier to use.  There are many ways to do this.  You could add an `attr_writer :to_param_flag` to your User model and set it in a `before_action` callback on the controller. You could store the logged_in state on User.  And there are many other solutions you can experiment with to find what best suites your project.

**Update:**

You can define the route a couple of ways.  Since there is only one route, instead of using resources we can use match. In the [match documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match), and [`ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base#match`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L469) usage and comments, we can see the the options (including `:param`) that we can use in `match`.

Therefore we can do:

```
resources :orders do
  match :order_confirmation, on: :member, param: :order_token, via: :get
end
```

and since [`get` is an alias for `match...via: :get`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L417) we can do:

```
resources :orders do
  get :order_confirmation, on: :member, param: :order_token
end
```

The routing will now be via `/orders/order_confirmation/:order_token` and the controller will have access to `params[:order_token]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What your saying is a bit over my head and/or just vague for my understanding in general.  I just updated my OP to include my routes.  Can you give me an example snippet code of what it would look like to accomplish this?  Essentially, I only want to have the SecureRandom in the URL for the order_confirmation method in the OrdersController.